# Prove that $F'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n'(x)$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $F_n$ is a sequence of increasing non-negative right continuous functions on $[0,1]$ such that $\sup_n F_n(1) < \infty$. Let $F = \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ and suppose that $F(1) < \infty$. Prove that 
$$F'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n'(x)$$
for almost every $x$.

My Attempt: Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue-Steiltjes measure induced by the increasing function $F$.  Since $\mu$ and $m$ are both finite, we can apply the Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem to get the decomposition $\mu = \lambda + \rho$.  Also, for each $n$, we get an induced Lebesgue-Steiltjes measure, $\mu_n$. Applying LDT for each $n$, we get $\mu_n = \lambda_n+\rho_n$, $m\perp\lambda$, and $\rho \ll m$. Since $F'$ exists a.e., we have 
\begin{align*}
F'(x) &= \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{F(x+r) - F(x)}{(x+r)-x}\\
&= \lim_{r\to0}\frac{\sum_n[F_n(x+r) - F_n(x)]}{(x+r)-x}\\
&= \lim_{r\to0} \frac{\sum_n\mu_n((x,x+r])}{m((x,x+r])}\\
&= \lim_{r\to0} \frac{\sum_n\lambda_n((x,x+r])}{m((x,x+r])}+ \frac{\sum_n\rho_n((x,x+r])}{m((x,x+r])}\\
&=0 + \lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{m((x,x+r])}\int_{(x,x+r]}\sum_nF_n'(y)dm
\end{align*}
We know that our Radon-Nikodym Derivatives are unique and thus, justifying the use of $F_n'(x)$ inside the integral. Since our measure space is finite and $(x,x+r] \subset [0,1]$, our functions $F_n'$ are locally integrable. Thus, we get that 
$$F'(x)  = \sum_nF_n'(x).$$

My problem is that I don't quite see where I'm using the conditions $\sup_n F_n(1) < \infty $ and $F(1) < \infty$.

Comment: does any1 have any hints or tips for this exercise?

Answer (score 1):

See  page 25 of [thispdf](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~bleary/AnalysisQual.pdf). For a different proof.